# git-flow how to have demo branches?

Tags: git, git-flow

We are a small team and work on a project using git and git-flow. Most of the time we develop towards one goal, so creating a feature and merging it when done to the develop branch works fine.

But now we are in the situation were we have multiple features, but we would want to only deploy a few features at a time and demo some other features.
I can't see a good way of doing this, so the only idea we have is to manually create a demo branch, merge the features we want to merge there and deploy it (for demo only). And once we decide that those features will be deployed, then we "git flow feature finish xxx" and do a deployment (as git-flow indicates).

We can do all that, but I was looking for best practices on how to approach this issue. I found this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22798684/git-flow-for-the-system-that-others-have-heavy-dependency-on) question which is similar to what I have but the answer is not satisfactory. So here I am.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `git-flow`, as far as I can tell, assumes that there is only one place to deploy to and that the `master` branch on every commit deploys there. In your situation, you have 2 deploy targets (live and demo). I think the a reasonable (though not perfect) place to "demo" things is the stabilisation branch. That can actually be deployed to a separate target after all the necessary stuff goes in and can then, once ready, be merged into master.

Comment: That would work if we are talking about 2 features, buy say you have 5 features and you want to group them 3-2 and you don't know which of them you will deploy first. What I would like is to be able to demo each group independently.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The [formal Git Flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) document has reference to a release branch.  Here I'd imagine that you would want to integrate all of the features that you have ready to go before release.

That branch seems to be the most ideal to showcase/demo what's upcoming in your releases.  It should also be the branch that QA is testing fervently before it's merged up into master.

Git can't manage the part about you not knowing which features are slated for a release, but if your project managers and your team work closely with each other, merging features like that to the release branch should work out well.

Comment: I don't think this is what Keyjote wants. From the question: "we would want to only deploy a few features at a time and demo some other features"

Comment: That's a process issue more than a Git issue.  If one wants to use the formal Git flow, then the release branch is where things go before a release, or when they want to demo specific things.

Comment: So how exactly would you deploy some features and demo some other features?

Comment: I do understand what Makoto says, but remember that a demo is not necesarily something ready to release. That is why the question and that is why I agree with @lubos

Answer (score 0):

Just create a demo branch out of develop and merge the features you want to demo:

> $ git checkout develop
>
> $ git branch demo
>
> $ git checkout demo
>
> $ git merge feature1
>
> $ git merge feature2

This is completely legit. It is cool if you have a mechanism (like git hook) to automatically deploy such a branch to some demo environment.

Comment: Aha 'git hook' I wasn't aware of that. Will look into it. I was looking for a best practice or reference to a standard way of doing this. Do you know of any? PS. Thanks for the answer

Comment: I have not found any reference for that, but I have seen many people use this approach. Actually, it is pretty straightforward: you should not use feature branch because that is where single feature is. You can't use develop because that is what is supposed to be released. You can't use release nor master nor hotfix for obvious reasons. So you just create a new branch. Branching is what git is great at.

Comment: your answer does help and gives me a bit more confidence to go this way, I was just hoping for references to best practices.